# OpenGL: Model doesn't look right when loaded in python

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I have a blender model and below is a image of how my model renders when I load it into python. It looks like the normals are all messed up. I am using the correct normal for each vertex. I'm exporting them in the correct order. I test this in the blender console that the actual export file had the right data.

I know that I had to rotate the model in python because z axis is different, so I'm not sure if the normals z is pointing in the wrong direction.

I'm using pyglet. Has anyone ever had this problem before?
Any ideas of what I can do to try to fix it?

Im not sure if this a OpenGL or python problem.

opengl setup code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    zNear = 0.01
    zFar = 1000.0
    fieldOfView = 45.0
    size = zNear * math.tan(math.radians(fieldOfView) / 2.0)
    glFrustum(-size, size, -size / (w / h), size / 
           (w / h), zNear, zFar); 
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);  
    # Set-up projection matrix
    # TODO


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)


    light0Ambient = (GLfloat * 4)(*[])
    light0Ambient[0] = 0.2
    light0Ambient[1] = 0.2
    light0Ambient[2] = 0.2
    light0Ambient[3] = 1.0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light0Ambient);


    lightpos = (GLfloat * 3)(*[])
    lightpos[0] = 5.0
    lightpos[1] = 5.0
    lightpos[2] = 5.0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightpos)


    tempLV = self.kjgCreateVectorWithStartandEndPoints((5.0,5.0,5.0), (0.0,0.0,-3.0))
    lightVector = (GLfloat * 3)(*[])
    lightVector[0] = tempLV[0]
    lightVector[1] = tempLV[1]
    lightVector[2] = tempLV[2]
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,lightVector);

    glLoadIdentity( )
    glTranslatef(0.0, 2.0, -18.0)
    #glScalef(0.4, 0.4, 0.4)
    glRotatef(-90, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Draw Code:

```
    for face in self.faces:
        #print group
        if len(face) == 3:
                glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
        elif len(face) == 4:
                glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        else:
                glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
        for i in face:
            if i in (104,16,18,102):
                    glVertex3f(*self.vertices[i])
                    color = self.calculateVertexIntensity((.5,.5,.5),self.normals[i],self.vertices[i])
                    glColor3f(*color)
                    glNormal3f(*self.normals[i])
        glEnd()
```

[image]

Comment: What's going on with setting the colour each vertex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you are specifying the normal **after** the vertex instead of **before**, so basically you're specifying the normal of vertex X for the vertex X+1. This is the most important flaw in the current code.

Also, what's that `calculateVertexIntensity`? First of all, lighting is enabled in your code so `glColor` is going to be ignored anyway, but still it looks like you tried to do something unnecessary here - the OpenGL fixed function rendering already will calculate the vertex intensity basing on the `glLight*` settings and `glMaterial*` settings.

Also, you might want to normalize your `lightVector`, I'm not sure whether OpenGL's going to normalize it for you.

*(Also make sure to check on the recent OpenGL features; you're using deprecated functions right now and because of that you'll soon hit a performance barrier. First thing too look for is `vertex arrays` or `VBO`, the next is `shaders`.)*

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with your normals.

The data in `self.normals` is probably wrong: you should recalculate normals making sure that you always use a sequence of vertices in the anticlockwise direction around the face to calculate each normal.

(also, you should be calling glNormal before drawing each vertex / face)

(also also, I don't know what's going on when you calculate the colour for each vertex: but check that that isn't causing problems)